# Read colours from a pointcloud2 python

Tags: python, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My issue is the following:

I have a kinect sensor and I want to parse its point cloud using Python.
I have subscribed to the topic and I am able to retrieve positional information of the pointcloud(x,y,z)

I now also need colour information but the read_points API does not seem to provide such [functionality](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/4440/point_cloud.py)

Is there any other tool I can use to also extract the colours in python? It seems I am doing something wrong since taking the point in cpp is, and I cannot believe I'm saying this, easier.

My code so far in the point extraction part is the following:

```
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
...............
# subscribe to pointcloud topic define the function that does the parsing
def PointCloud(self, PointCloud2):
    self.lock.acquire()
    gen = pc2.read_points(PointCloud2, skip_nans=True, field_names=("x" , "y" , " z" ))
    int_data = list(gen)
    print int_data[0] #Gives first point etc
    self.lock.release()
```

I tried adding field_names but the read_points API made it clear it does not work that way.
Any thoughts on a fast way to also extract colour info from my pointcloud?

Thanks in advance,

Panos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208834/read-colours-from-a-pointcloud2-python/) by [panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/22350/panos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fix was actually to first remove the field_names from the read_points input parameters.

That way the function output 4 values per line instead of 3.

Taking the last value of that list and doing the required bitwise operations to retrieves the individual r,g,b values.

My code in case someone needs it in the future is the following:

```
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pc2
import ctypes
import struct
...............
# subscribe to pointcloud topic define the function that does the parsing
def PointCloud(self, PointCloud2):
    self.lock.acquire()
    gen = pc2.read_points(PointCloud2, skip_nans=True)
    int_data = list(gen)
    for x in int_data:
        test = x[3] 
        # cast float32 to int so that bitwise operations are possible
        s = struct.pack('>f' ,test)
        i = struct.unpack('>l',s)[0]
        # you can get back the float value by the inverse operations
        pack = ctypes.c_uint32(i).value
        r = (pack & 0x00FF0000)>> 16
        g = (pack & 0x0000FF00)>> 8
        b = (pack & 0x0000FF00)
        print r,g,b # prints r,g,b values in the 0-255 range
                    # x,y,z can be retrieved from the x[0],x[1],x[2]
    self.lock.release()
```

---

Originally posted by [panos](https://answers.ros.org/users/22350/panos/) with karma: 43 on 2015-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kapoor_amita](https://answers.ros.org/users/28643/kapoor_amita/) on 2016-12-14**:
Is it possible to do it in matrix format, instead of element form.

**Comment by [MartyMcFly](https://answers.ros.org/users/28860/martymcfly/) on 2016-12-20**:
@panos Thanks for the code!!

I think there is a typo here.  It looks like the last bit mask should be:

```
b = (pack & 0x000000FF)
```

instead of:

```
b = (pack & 0x0000FF00)
```

**Comment by [Srijal](https://answers.ros.org/users/33014/srijal/) on 2018-06-07**:
This worked for me. Thank you!